# Can Jetbrains GoLand use both GoModule and GOPATH?

Tags: go, goland

I'm working in ***fibrechannel*** project, and there are same level project(***common***) that fibrechannel depends on.

When I select `Enable Go modules integration` as below:

[image]

IDE tells me logger not found. (Note I'm using red rectangle to mark the reference and it's actually location under ***common*** folder)

[image]

After I unclick the `Enable Go modules integration` checkbox. (Note GOPATH looks like below)

[image]

IDE tells me "github.com/pkg/errors" not found.

[image]

the *go.mod* under ***fibrechannel*** looks like below:

```
module fibrechannel/src

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.1
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.3.0
    gopkg.in/iconv.v1 v1.1.1
    gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.2
)
```

I'm a newbie in GO language, and I just want the IDE to resolve dependencies successfully.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make both GOPATH and GoModules work in Jetbrains GoLand. If not, is there a way to modify go.mod so that it can include GOPATH?

Comment: Module support has been considered ready for production use since Go 1.14 ([source](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)) and the ability to use `GOPATH` for this [will probably be removed at some point](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH#deprecating-and-removing-gopath-development-mode). As someone new to Go I'd suggest sticking with Modules. You can use [`require`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-require) to pull in files from outside the current module (or, if using go 1.18, a [workspace](https://go.dev/ref/mod#workspaces)).

Comment: Thanks @Brits! I'm using go 1.17.8. So I suppose I should use require to pull in files from outside the current module. I digged a little and it looks like even though it's just a internal module, I have to use something like example.com/common/src. But what I need is just common/src, which is not allowed, this is really frustrating!

Comment: Sorry I meant [`replace`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) not `require` (replace allows you to tell go to look for the module somewhere else; including on the filesystem). Here is an example in [the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/yHlZfFZsTJ9) (I'm using a made-up URL and you can too but its worth considering using a git repo).

Comment: Thanks you @Brits, I found that keyword too. But when I play with it, I noticed that the local package must be named as "example.com/common/src". Since it's a public project, I shouldn't change anything. That's why I switched to other solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I managed to solve this issue.

B.T.W, since this is an old project maintained by many team members. I don't want to change its code structure, all I need is to read the content without any unknown reference in GoLand.

The solution is NOT to use go modules.

I unchecked the `Enable Go modules integration` so that only libraries in `venders` folder not found.

Then I manually added `venders` folder into GOPATH.

[image]

Now dependencies are all resolved!